# Get reminders based on data in a database

Tags: xamarin, android-jobscheduler

I want to get reminders for some Appointments that I have saved in database and they have a notificationTime property witch is the time when a notification needs to be displayed.

My approach so far is to write some kind of job that runs 1 or 2 times a day to pull the notifications that need to be registered in the next 24h and ofc register them (if you guys have a better ideea lmk :D )

This works BUT:

- Only if the app is in foreground / background; then I get notification every 15min or so;
- If I KILL the app I don't receive notification on my physical device (Xiaomi Redmi Note 9 Pro with Android version 12 SKQ),
  only on the virtual one (Pixel 5 Android 13)

Right now I have a class that extends JobService and I use JobScheduler to schedule the Job to run every 15 min (for testing so I don't need to w8 12h xD )

Here is the JobScheduler witch I call in MainActivity file in OnCreate method

```
 Console.WriteLine("Schedualing job");
            TimeSpan interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);

            var javaClass = Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(NotificationService));
            var componentName = new ComponentName(Application.Context, javaClass);

            var jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(1, componentName)
                .SetPeriodic(15 * 60 * 1000, 30 * 60 * 1000)
                .SetRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.Any)
                .SetPersisted(true)
                .Build();
            
            var jobScheduler = (JobScheduler)GetSystemService(JobSchedulerService);
            var resultCode = jobScheduler.Schedule(jobInfo);
```

and here is the NotificationService.cs

```
[Service(Name = "com.companyname.deratizare_mobile.NotificationService",
        Permission = "android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE")]
    public class NotificationService : JobService
    {
        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {
            return StartCommandResult.StickyCompatibility;
        }

        public override bool OnStartJob(JobParameters @params)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Job started");
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                //var hasSuccessful = await ProccessNotificationToRegister();
                var notification = new NotificationRequest
                {
                    Title = "Job",
                    Description = $"Description",
                    Schedule = new NotificationRequestSchedule
                    {
                        NotifyTime = DateTime.Now,
                    }
                };

                LocalNotificationCenter.Current.Show(notification);
                JobFinished(@params, false);
            Console.WriteLine("Job finished");
            });
            return true;
        }

        public override bool OnStopJob(JobParameters @params)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Job stopped");
            return true;
        }
}
```

AndroidManifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**UPDATE**

I have given permission to auto start to my app from the device and it works

**SOLUTION**

I ended up using FCM and a hosted service on the server that checks the cache every 5 minutes where I have stored the next notification that needs to be displaied

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Firebase push notifications.

With push notifications, you can update your users without requiring the app to run at all times or having it poll a server, potentially running down the battery.

For more information, you can check [Implementing Push Notifications in Your Android Apps](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/implementing-push-notifications-android-apps/) and [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/firebase-cloud-messaging).

Comment: Is push notification a better option even if I have a few users only? And that will be the maximum, no new users will join. Also I still need some kind of service to run once a day to push notifications to the client right?

Comment: Due to Android battery optimizations introduced in Android 8.0 (API level 26), background services have now some important [limitations](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#services). Essentially, they are killed once the app is in background for a while making them worthless for our purpose of running an always-running service. In most cases, apps can work around these limitations by using [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler) jobs.

Comment: I have implemented push notifications but I lost the scheduling functionality as that was handled on xamarin by JobScheduler. Any suggestions for building one in .NET or a replacement?

Comment: For this,you can check document [Android Job Scheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/android-job-scheduler) .